# Record locking in Innodb, is this certain to work

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

This table has two fields, Price and amount.

I am performing a query on this innodb table which Selects for update all records whose price is less than 100 (query 1).

1. Whilst this query is going on, I want to be able to insert or update a row in the table which has a price greather 100. Is this certain to work?
2. At the same time, I want to guarantee that any attempts to update or insert rows into the table, whose price is less than 100 will not happen until (query 1) is complete. Is this also certain?
3. If I want to perform ordinary select * from queries on this table whilst queries of type 1 are happening, and queries in question 2, will I be able to do these reads or will these reads have to wait until the locks are off? This has to be certain. edit: I would like these selects to be able to access any record in the table
4. Finally, are indexes crucial to get this working? Or will it work as is?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your table only has two fields (price and amount), this seems… bad. Surely there should be some sort of other identifier in there?

1. Yes. `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only locks the records it selected.
2. Maybe. Depending on your [transaction isolation mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html), MySQL may lock an index range to block inserts into the range that was scanned as part of your query.
3. This depends on the transaction isolation mode you use. If you are using a higher isolation mode, locking the rows for update will prevent them from being read, as your transaction may or may not end up making changes to them, depending on whether it is committed. See the MySQL manual's section on "[`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` Locking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)" for details.
4. Yes. The index range locking mentioned in part 2 depends on there being an index. Running unindexed queries is a bad idea, anyway — avoid it.

Comment: Regarding point 3 then, is there a way to read records that are currently going through a "SELECT FOR UPDATE" query? Is so, please advise. The link is informative but I can't see how to do it. Thanks for the other answers.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your current [transaction isolation mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html). (Based on some information I was surprised by there, I've updated some other points.)

Comment: Just to clarify, the reads would be blocked if your TX ISOLATION level is SERIALIZABLE or REPEATABLE-READ, and would not be blocked if the level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED

Comment: Correct. And keep in mind that "blocked" means that the read will wait until the transaction finishes, not that it will fail outright.